# Slicing a wxPython WindowList

Tags: python, wxpython, slice

In a GUI, I use a `wx.Treebook` filled with many `wx.lib.agw.ultimatelistctrl`s (ULCs).

I need to traverse the treebook pages (a.k.a. the ULCs).
I use `lPages = treebook.GetChildren()` to get them.

However, the first children of the treebook is an instance of `wx.TreeCtrl`.

I know I could avoid it with something like:

```
for page in lPages:
    if not isinstance( page, wx.TreeCtrl ):
        # do something with the ULCs
```

But I would like to keep my code simple and easily readable. Thus, not use a test for a single use and preserve the extra indent.
I would like to do something like `lPages = treebook.GetChildren()[1:]` or `del lPages[0]` to only get the ULCs.

It gives me the following errors:

Using `treebook.GetChildren()[1:]`:

```
TypeError: WindowList.__getitem__(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'slice'
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Using `del lPages[0]`:

```
TypeError: 'WindowList' object doesn't support item deletion
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Is there any way to slice a WindowList?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The object returned by `GetChildren` is not an actual Python list, but rather a C++ object that mimics some of the behavior of a list.  You can convert it to a real list using `list()`, like this:

```
lPages = list(treebook.GetChildren())
```

Then you can do your slicing or whatever you need on that list object.  Note that  changing the order of or removing items from `lPages` does not affect the actual children of the window.  Once you convert it to a `list()` then that is just a copy of the original collection.

Comment: Apparently wxWindowList is defined here -- https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/821c2a07fe2b29c283e11f25b184e3d6d9a17013/include/wx/window.h#L153